# Grilled Fish Kebabs

Tags: fish, grilling, barbecue

The barbecue season is in full swing, and to take a break from the red-meat heavy traditionals, I decided to try and explore the world for grilled fish. My first attempt was to briefly marinate some pangasius in olive oil, garlic and lemon juice and then stick it on a bamboo stick with thin slices of bacon in between the fish.

It was nice, but something tells me there are better experiences to be had.

How do I make white fish off the grill a memorable experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try marinading chunks (about 4cm square) of haddock in a [chermoula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chermoula) for a few hours.  Make up skewers with the fish interspersed with pieces of pepper and cherry tomatoes.  There are many recipes for chermoula marinade, but I think one with a fair amount of fresh coriander and smoky paprika works well.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to sound like a broken record, but I really love fish tacos (Mahi-Mahi is the best in my opinion):

- 1 fish (or more if they're small)
- Lime
- Olive Oil
- Chili Powder
- Cumin
- Salsas, guacamole, chilies, cabbage salad, etc. for topping

Squeeze some lime on the fish, and rub down with chili powder and cumin (if you use American Chili Powder, you don't need extra cumin, but I would recommend real chili powder). Massage in oil.

Let stand for a few minutes, up to a few hours.

Toss skin side down on foil over a hot grill, and cook until the flesh separates when poked.

Serve immediately with any salads you like.

**Edit:**

You could also smoke it.

Brine before hand for a day or so in a simple brine with sugar and salt, spices at your digressions. Remove from brine and let sit, uncovered, in the fridge for 12-24 hours (allows protein to come to the surface and dry, which will later attract smoke). Smoke.

Good Eats had a few episodes on smoking showing how to make a home smoker for a few bucks out of various things (a box, a gym locker, an ammo box and a large clay pot in different episodes).

Answer (score 1):

You can either try some form of a fish cake and make it into a "kofta" meat ball or

you can try meatier fish like tuna marinated in the thai sauce of your choice. Lightly sear the edges and your done.

however, I'm not really sure that you're going to gain more flavor cooking fish that way. if you want bite size pieces, then your alternative is to cut and cook some very small pieces of salmon, put it on some rice crackers, a little bit of wassabi, a drizzle of soy sauce and a bit of chives on top. I think that'll achieve the lightness, the tantalizingness in the fish.